# Why runtime can not recognize string defined in "res/values/strings.xml"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-intent, android-widget

I have an activity:

```
public class Notepadv1 extends ListActivity {

   public static final int INSERT_ID = Menu.FIRST;
   ...
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert); //problem here

        return result;
    }
  ...
}
```

my `res/values/strings.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Notepad v1</string>
    <string name="no_notes">No Notes Yet</string>
    <string name="menu_insert">Add Item</string>
</resources>
```

Then, I run my application on emulator. After the app launched, When I press the "**menu**" button I expect to have a "**Add Item**" option to show up on menu, but I got error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  631): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime(  631): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f040002
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:200)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:253)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.add(MenuBuilder.java:397)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at com.android.demo.notepad1.Notepadv1.onCreateOptionsMenu(Notepadv1.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:305)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDownPanel(PhoneWindow.java:550)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onKeyDown(PhoneWindow.java:1192)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1636)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2368)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2338)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1641)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime(  631):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
...
```

It seems the android runtime can not recogonize my **"menu_insert"** vaue defined in `res/values/strings.xml` , why? where am I wrong?

Comment: Did you try to clean and refresh your project before running again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaning your project (Project -> Clean) might help.